# What should be a method prefix that makes calculation based on the parameter

Tags: naming, methods

I have a method, that takes a list of students, and returns the student with the best score.

Part of me wants to call it `Student getBestStudent(List<Student> students)`, but I think that `get` refers to the methods, that make a relatively heavy database/service calls. Here I do just simple filtering.

Another part of me wants to call it `Student extractBestStudent(List<Student> students)`, because I want to specify in the name, that this method makes light computations based only on the parameter.

What's the best way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Names depend a lot on the programming language, its community, and the surrounding code base.

I would probably call the function `bestStudent()` because that is what the function returns. But that is a noun, not a verb. Functional programmers are fine with functions representing results, not just actions. **Such names are also in line with Java conventions**. For example the Java collections have methods like `indexOf()` (not `getIndexOf()`) or `size()` (not `getSize()`).

An OOP programmer might prefer the name to contain a verb, at least for methods that modify their object.

Methods are often prefixed with `get` just to turn them into a verb. For example, in Java it is the convention get/set prefixes are used for the getter and setter methods of a private field. In Java, this is coupled with the expectation that a `getFoo()` method will be very cheap, so no database queries involved (`loadFoo()` might be a better name if data is fetched externally).

In your case, the method isn't particularly cheap because it doesn't retrieve a value that already exists. So I don't think `getBestStudent()` is perfect, though it's a completely acceptable name. When I look at that method's behaviour, I see that it is *searching* the list for the best student. Instead of `extract`, I'd suggest to consider `findBestStudent()`.